# MYSQL group stats by range of two dates for statistics

Tags: mysql, group-by, statistics

I try to implement some statistics in my app.

Actually I wqnt to display all "sales" (number of orders and total amount) for a range of two dates.

I use the following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(order.id), SUM(order.total_amount) FROM `order` WHERE payed_at BETWEEN "2015-07-01 00:00:00" AND "2015-08-25 00:00:00"
```

It works for the range. Now I would like to zoom like I would like to group by "all days of the range", "all monthes of the range"

eg for all days of the range :

- |2015-07-01 | 0 | 0 |
- |2015-07-02 | 1 | 3000 |
- ...
- |2015-08-20 | 3 | 450 |

eg for all months of the range :

- |2015-07-01 | 40 | 15200 |
- |2015-08-01 | 23 | 3890 |

Is it possible to perform that with the same query, just adding something like "GROUP BY" ?

I know a lot of different way to go to the result I want... but for one time, I would like to do a clean thing with MySQL, something a little bit "professional".

Nice day

Comment: Did you try using GROUP BY?  e.g:  `GROUP BY month(payed_at)`

Comment: Ok, after retry with some improvements, it seems it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something funky with `UNION ALL` but I'd probably keep the three queries separate.

You'll probably want some application code to render the results into a table or graph of some sorts anyway and I'd take the overhead of three calls.

I'd run the queries as follows:

```
  SELECT COUNT(order.id), 
         SUM(order.total_amount) 
    FROM `order` 
   WHERE payed_at >= :start_date 
     AND payed_at <  :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY

  SELECT DATE(payed_at) payed_date
         COUNT(order.id), 
         SUM(order.total_amount) 
    FROM `order` 
   WHERE payed_at >= :start_date 
     AND payed_at <  :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY payed_date

  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM payed_at) payed_year_month
         COUNT(order.id), 
         SUM(order.total_amount) 
    FROM `order` 
   WHERE payed_at >= :start_date 
     AND payed_at <  :end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY payed_year_month
```

I prefer the exact logic of `>=`/`<` when querying date ranges over the inclusive `BETWEEN`.

When grouping by month it is usually important to remember to include the year as well if the range can span a year. Alternatives to `EXTRACT` include `LAST_DAY` and `DATE_FORMAT`.. see [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Another option is to only run the 2nd query (grouped by date) and roll-up the month and range totals in application code.

Comment: The three queries do the job. I will use something like that if I don't find another way to do this. At start I would use the exactly same request and play with the GROUP BY DAY/MONTH ... but my test are not good actually. BTW, big thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.. please accept the answer if you end up using it :)

Comment: I'll wait a little bit to see if someone else have another idea. Else, I will accept it tomorrow